# Can't run Nodeschool workshops

Tags: node.js

I've installed latest version of Node and NPM.  All OK

I've run npm install -g javascripting. All OK.

But when I run 'javascripting', I just get an error "-bash: javascripting: command not found".

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing?

Thanks

Jason

Comment: How did you install npm?

Comment: As part of Nodejs.  I just ran the nodejs installer from the website, which includes NPM with it

Comment: What is the output of npm prefix -g

Comment: Hi Yuri, output is: /Users/jason/.node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add /Users/jason/.node/bin to /etc/paths

Comment: I have added  PATH=/Users/jason/.node/bin:$PATH  to my ~/.bashrc, but still no good ..  -bash: javascripting: command not found when I install and run javascripting

Comment: If I go into /Users/jason/.node/bin i can see javascripting there.  If I run 'javascripting', I get the same error, but if I run './javascripting', it runs fine.   So it looks like it is installing fine, but just an issue running it as a command.

Comment: Yuri, I found it.  I needed to add /Users/jason/.node/bin to /etc/paths.  http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.VPpVBWTLf_k.  If you can update your answer to this I'll flag as answer.  Thanks for your help Yuri!!